# If I type www.mydomain.com the page is displayed, if I type the IP XXX.XX.XXX.XX, I get apache's default page

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Sorry for the long title, but I have no idea about what else to put. My problem is exactly that. If I type www.mydomain.com the right page is displayed, if I type the IP XXX.XX.XXX.XX, I get apache's default page.

my VirtualHost file is:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:443

    <VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin myname@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/site/rails-webpage/public

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/user/doc/www_desmangeo_it.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user/doc/desmangeo.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/user/doc/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

    <Directory /home/user/site/rails-webpage/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

Thanks to the comment given by Ray I noticed that if I make the IP request using https, I get to the right page. So it seems I'm not "redirecting the views at port 80". I mean, when I tried to do it using port 80 I got a SSL error. So I need to use port 443. How do I tell the server to "switch" to port 443?

[EDIT] So I loaded the rewrite module using

```
    sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and added

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

at the beggining of the file where my virtualhost is. Nothing.

Comment: Are you connecting with https or http when you try to access the ip directly?

Comment: Ok. You asked the right question. I hadn't check that out. If I do http, I get the apache page. If I type https://XXX.XX.XX.XXX (doing https), I get the correct page. What did I miss?

Comment: Your `VirtualHost` directive says port 443, which is used only for HTTPS, not HTTP.

Comment: Could you please expand the idea? That's correct. I need to use https. So I should use port 443 right? I'll add more info to the question.

Comment: You need to add another site definition for HTTP (port 80). It could contain a `RewriteRule` to redirect people to the HTTPS version

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tried but cannot figure out how to do it. Posted the code I used on the question.

Comment: @cauchy See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual host file is only looking to match on port 443-- https.  You need to create a second one that listens on post 80.  This second one will have all the same info, just not the port 443 in the declaration (or any of the certificate details).

The default configuration for apache is catching all your port 80 requests.

Here is the declaration block you need to change:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

      #.... details here

    </VirtualHost>
```

[EDIT] This worked:

```
    <VirtualHost xxx.xx.xx.xxx:80>
            redirect / www.mysite.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @cauchy you need to remove all the SSL stuff from the port 80 vhost

Comment: I did remove it. Maybe I have an error somewhere else too. But If make a second virtualhost that listens to port 80, how do I get ssl on port 80? I need ssl.

Comment: @cauchy you don't.  Post 80 is only for http (typically).  So what you want is to catch any non-https traffic and redirect it to your https vhost?

Comment: If this is the only site you have and you want 100% of traffic to go to https, put your rewrite with the default apache port 80 route.

Comment: I figure it out. Instead of the * I put the IP -have no idea why that works and the other way doesn't - and made a redirect using: Redirect permanent / https://www.mysite.com/  Do you mind I edit your answer, so I can give you the correct answer mark?

Comment: @cauchy glad specifying the ip worked.  Feel free to edit as you choose.